# How can I change the duplicate letters of a string?

Tags: python, list, replace, duplicates

I tried to solve this

convert a string to
a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only
once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once.

It was supposed to be like this

```
"din" => "((("
"recede" => "()()()"
```

I wrote the following code but I can´t change the duplicate characters into ')' for instance the 3 "e" in "recede" what should I do?

```
def change_str(str):
    string str
    lis = list(string)
    count_letter = len(lis)

    lis = '('*count letter
    print(lis)

change_str("received")
```

Comment: `len(lis)` just gives you the *length of the string*...

Answer (score 0):

you may want to do something like this.

```
s1 = "din"
s2 = "recede"


def change_str(string):
    new_str = ""
    for letter in string:
        if string.count(letter) == 1:
            new_str += "("
        elif string.count(letter) > 1:
            new_str += ")"
    return new_str


print(change_str(s1))
print(change_str(s2))
```

also, you don't declare types in Python like you do in C++

Comment: Your approach is not efficient; it performs O(n^2) operations. You can optimize this by initially counting the letters.

Comment: yea, I wrote the simplest approach for him to understand the logic behind it

Answer (score 0):

First, make a count of characters and then use `str.join`:

```py
def change_str(s):
    counts = {}
    for ch in s:
        counts[ch] = counts.get(ch, 0) + 1

    return "".join("(" if counts[ch] == 1 else ")" for ch in s)


print(change_str("recede"))
```

Prints:

```
()()()
```

Comment: Sorry what is that counts.get(ch, 0) + 1 part? what does that do?

Comment: @ArikyHito it returns the value of counts[ch] if present, otherwise returns 0. it's used to increment counts[ch] avoiding returning None on the first increment.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is a little bit shorter:

```
def convert_string(string):
    return ''.join(['(' if s.count(char) == 1 else ')' for char in string])

# Test cases
print(convert_string("din"))      # Outputs: (((
print(convert_string("recede"))   # Outputs: ()()()
```

1. You're using a list comprehension to generate a list that contains the desired symbols "(" or ")" for each character in the string.
2. You use the str.count() method to determine how many times each character appears in the string.
3. Then you use join to combine the list of symbols back into a single string.